# Group by reversible pair

Tags: mysql, group-by

I'm sure my title is not clear enough...

Let's say I have a "chat" table, storing individual messages like this:

```
message_id, from_user_id, to_user_id, timestamp
```

For a given user_id, I want a list of "conversations" for this user. A conversation would be all messages involving the same 2 users. Kinda of like Facebook.

What would be the best way to achieve this? I was starting to write a simple query with GROUP BY but then realized the pair of user ids could be both ways - but to me it's still the same conversation.

```
SELECT * FROM message WHERE (from_id = 1 OR to_id = 1) GROUP BY ... ??
```

Comment: I think you need a self join

Comment: Do you want to count them or show all of them? In the second case, you don't want to use `GROUP BY`.

Comment: I want show them (not individual messages, but conversations, sorted by latest activity)

Comment: And how do you know which message belongs to which conversation? You mean all messages between two users constitute a conversation?

Comment: yes @ypercube .

Comment: I took a different approach, I created a hash combining both user ids (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21515318/create-a-unique-string-given-2-parameters-regardless-of-order) and used that to identify each conversations.

Answer (score 3):

You can use a `UNION` of two subqueries:

```
SELECT 
    user_id,
    MAX(ts)  AS last_timestamp,
    SUM(cnt) AS number_of_messages
FROM
  ( SELECT  to_user_id AS user_id,
            MAX(timestamp) AS ts,
            COUNT(*) AS cnt
    FROM chat
    WHERE from_user_id = 1
    GROUP BY to_user_id 
  UNION ALL
    SELECT  from_user_id AS user_id,
            MAX(timestamp) AS ts,
            COUNT(*) AS cnt
    FROM chat
    WHERE to_user_id = 1
    GROUP BY from_user_id 
  ) AS tmp 
GROUP BY 
    user_id ;
```

Two indexes, on `(from_user_id, to_user_id, timestamp)` and `(to_user_id, from_user_id, timestamp)` would help efficiency of the subqueries.

Comment: Thank you. It looks good, however I took a simpler approach by getting some help from php. I created a hash combining both user ids (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21515318/create-a-unique-string-given-2-parameters-regardless-of-order) and used that to identify each conversations. I added a conversation field, and was able to use a simple GROUP BY conversation.

Answer (score 2):

I know it's a late answer but I created this to do a similar thing in an application:

```
SELECT * FROM message WHERE (from_id = 1 OR to_id = 1) GROUP BY
CONCAT(GREATEST(from_id,to_id), '-', LEAST(from_id,to_id))
```

Hopefully this helps someone :)

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT *
  FROM message
 WHERE (from_id = 1 OR to_id = 1)
 GROUP BY IF(from_id=1, to_id, from_id)
```

Comment: Could you please explain how the part that is different (`IF`) works?  That would make your answer more valuable than just a piece of code.

Comment: I think the meaning is clear as the code presents.  Take some example data:

Comment: it will put all pairs which contain the given id (here is 1) and the same opposite id into one group.